# Lua - For loops: saving the value of the control variable

Tags: lua

I'm having a hard time understanding the example from the doc(https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.4.html) and need some clarification.

> If you need the value of the control variable after the loop (usually when you break the loop), you must save this value into another variable:
>
> ```
> -- find a value in a list
> local found = nil
> for i=1,a.n do
>   if a[i] == value then
>     found = i      -- save value of `i'
>     break
>   end
> end
> print(found)
> ```

I don't understand the `a.n` and `if a[i] == value then` parts. Are they creating a table `a={n=5,...}` and calling a single value like `a.n=5`?

I think I need a written explanation of what's occurring in the example, and what is missing, or a complete example. I'm guessing its missing the declaration of table/variables...?

Cause `a[i]` is calling entries of `a={}` and I don't understand what 'value' is...? A variable I have to declare first and then set to a specific value...? What value though?

Why am I calling other entries in a table (i.e. `a[i]`) when I'm defining `a.n` as the entry I want to be dealing with?

And in this case do I have to define the entry I want the control variable to break on by predefining the number and that's what value is set to...?

That would defeat the point of calling the value of the control variable if I already define what its going to be. I'm very confused. Like I understand if the example was:

```
local found = nil
local a=7
for i=1,a do
  print(i)
  found=a
  break
end
```

However `print(found)` is equal to 7 rather than the last iteration of the incomplete `for` loop (2 or 1?).

What I was looking for was a way to save whatever number the control variable was on when the loop was interrupted.

So if it was `for i=1,5 do`... and the last printed iteration was 4, how would I call this value? I'm unsure if the doc is providing that in its example or not.

Comment: `Are they creating a table a={n=5,...} and calling a single value like a.n=5?` Yes.  Field `n` is frequently used to contain the length of the array

Comment: Does this "value" have to be declared...? What is the point of declaring local found = nil if nothing else is being declared? What is a[i] going to be? Doesn't it have to be i=1 if its a={n=5}? But doesn't that only work when ur doing one loop. I only see this working for a.n[i] = value where a={n={1,2,3...}}, but its written as a[i]. I need a working example, I can't tell if what's written is working code or a fill in the blanks. Can someone provide an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete working example may be the following:

```
local function find_value_in_list(value, a)
    -- find a value in a list and print its index
    local found = nil
    for i=1, a.n do
      if a[i] == value then
        found = i      -- save value of `i'
        break
      end
    end
    print(found)
end    

find_value_in_list(33, {n=4, 11, 22, 33, 44})  --> 3
find_value_in_list(42, {n=4, 11, 22, 33, 44})  --> nil
```

Comment: OKay I understand. This is setting a loop where it breaks on the desired value in a table, and then records the control variable's index at that break as the variable "found". Question though: you say Field n (I'm guessing field is the same as an entry in a table i.e. 'entry n') is frequently used to contain the length of the array. But field n is an entry in the table as well. So if I wanted to print the length of the table with #table I'd get a value of 5, yet n=4? Is it the norm to assume an array (which is just a table setup to be numbers) has #table-1 entries...?

Comment: I also don't understand why, if I define the table as a, print(a[3]) is giving me the value of 33. The third index is 22..? Why is print(a[1])=11, I woulda thought it would be  =n=4. Edit: Okay nevermind from my testing I see that variables are excluded from the index of the table.

Comment: @kite [The length operator](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.7) only applies to fields with *integer* keys in a table. `n` is not a variable in this case, but a string key of value `"n"`.